How do I update Eclipse?
I get a weird console output when running a class in Eclipse:
JRE Oracle Corporation/22.0.1 is not supported, advanced source lookup disabled. Eclipse debugger will use less precise source lookup implementation for this debug session, but everything else will continue to work otherwise. Upgrading Eclipse to the latest version will likely make this warning go away.
How do i fix it?
I tried searching for updates but nothing found.
About Eclipse IDE:
Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0)
Build id: 20240307-1437

Use Help > Check for Updates to update to 2024-06 to get support for Java 22 (Java 22 was released after Eclipse 2024-03 so a newer version of Eclipse is required to use Java 22 in your projects).

Check that you have the required update sites configured under Window-> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Update Sites. Some sites that could be helpful are https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2024-06 and https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest. Some 3rd party plugins might impose restrictions on updates if they specify that only osgi packages up until some version are required.

go to the Marketplace (Help -> Eclipse Marketplace) and search for "Java 22", select  Java 22 Support for Eclipse 2024-03 (or similar as appropriate,) and install it

@user85421 Better update to Eclipse 2024-06.

Use Help > Check for Updates to update to 2024-06 to get support for Java 22 (Java 22 was released after Eclipse 2024-03 so a newer version of Eclipse is required to use Java 22 in your projects).
– @howlger
