What is causing this error when upgrading Eclipse?
On macbook pro, currently running Eclipse 2023-09 (4.29.0)
When I check for updates, I get this error:
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  Software being installed: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers 4.32.0.20240606-1231 (epp.package.jee 4.32.0.20240606-1231)
  Software being installed: JustJ Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete 20.0.1.v20230425-1611 (org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.feature.group 20.0.1.v20230425-1611)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers 4.32.0.20240606-1231 (epp.package.jee 4.32.0.20240606-1231)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.epp.package.common.feature.feature.group [4.32.0.20240606-1231,4.32.0.20240606-1231]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Common EPP Bundle 4.32.0.20240606-1231 (org.eclipse.epp.package.common 4.32.0.20240606-1231)
    To: osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=21))
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Packaging Project Common Feature 4.32.0.20240606-1231 (org.eclipse.epp.package.common.feature.feature.group 4.32.0.20240606-1231)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.epp.package.common [4.32.0.20240606-1231,4.32.0.20240606-1231]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JustJ Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete 20.0.1.v20230425-1611 (org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full 20.0.1.v20230425-1611)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; a.jre.javase 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JustJ Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete 20.0.1.v20230425-1611 (org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.feature.group 20.0.1.v20230425-1611)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full [20.0.1.v20230425-1611,20.0.1.v20230425-1611]

What do I need to do?
Thanks!

Normally checking for updates shouldn't try to bring in a completely new release, never mind one three releases newer. What steps did you perform before checking for updates?

Hmm, well I was hoping to upgrade to a new release actually, and was following instructions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78671415/how-do-i-update-eclipse that said "Some sites that could be helpful are download.eclipse.org/releases/2024-06 and download.eclipse.org/releases/latest", so I added those. But it was failing to update before I even added those with the same error message (not sure if it was the same packages)

The change in required Java versions causes some problems. Try to Install the "JustJ Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete" from https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/21/updates/release/latest/ first, then check for updates after letting it restart.

Thanks so much for your help @nitind ! Upgrade proceeded smoothly after that.

The change in required Java versions causes some problems. Try to Install a newer "JustJ Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete" from https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/21/updates/release/latest first, let Eclipse restart, then check for updates again.

This worked for me. Details: add this URL. Then check for update, deselect other packages, only select "JustJ Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete", upgrade, restart, then upgrade the rest.

In my case I went into "Install new software" and added the missing java 21 updates site as you provided above and then just retried the update and all was well.
